# Conservation of flow rate through pump (compressible flow)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, flow

I am confused about conservation of mass through a pump for a compressible flow.

Do we have conservation of mass flow rate between the inlet and the outlet, conservation of volumetric flow rate, or both? Because I guess the density of the gas would increase while flowing throuth the pump, isn't it?

An example would be a pump connected to a gas tank in order to drain it. The sentence "What goes in the pump goes out." would be true in terms of volume or in terms of mass?

Comment: Many developments for pumps assume an incompressible liquid and as such constant mass rate is constant volume rate.  Suggest you look for details for a compressor for evaluating the flow of a compressible fluid.

Comment: Mass is conserved.  Volume isn't.

Comment: As everyone is saying, mass in conserved, so in the end, mass in equals mass out. **But**, in practice, the "mass in" will change for different types of pumps for compressible flow, and that will be the key point, even though your question (accidentally or carefully, I can't tell) avoids explicitly addressing this.

Answer (score 0):

The continuity equation is based on the law of conservation of mass
$$\dot{m}_{in} = \dot{m}_{out}$$
Here $\dot{m}$ is the mass flow rate

From the above equation, for any flow
$$\rho_{in} \dot{V}_{in} = \rho_{out} \dot{V}_{out}$$

If the flow is incompressible ($\rho_{in} = \rho_{out}$), then the above equation reduces to
$$\dot{V}_{in} = \dot{V}_{out}$$
However, this won't be true if the flow is compressible.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether the flow is compressible or incompressible, under steady flow conditions the mass flow rate $\dot m$ is constant for conservation of mass.

For incompressible flow, the volume flow rate $\dot V$ is also constant since the density $m/V$ is constant.

But for compressible flow $\dot V$ is not constant since density $m/V$ is not constant.

Hope this helps.